# Como rodar uma aplicação Angular com Node.JS e Express

Tags: node.js, express.js

Como faço para linkar uma aplicação de login desenvolvida em angular com o servidor do Node.JS e Express. Como faço para testar(puxar) a aplicação para o servidor.

O servidor está funcionando normalmente na porta 3000:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = '3000';

var app = express();

app.listen(port);

app.get('/login.html', function(req, res){
    var pessoa = {
        nome:'Leandro', 
        país:'Brasil',
        cpf:'457898'
    };
    res.json(pessoa);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente puxo assim

> server.js
>
> > pastaDoProjeto
> >
> > > index.html

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pastaDoProjeto'));
app.use(bodyParser());

var porta = 3412;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || porta, function(){
    console.log('Servidor online porta ' + porta);
});
```

Comment: Então @Felipe Duarte no node apareceu aqui que o BodyParser está deprecated e não funciona.

Comment: faz tempo que não mexo com node, mas isso se não me engano é um warning que não interrompe seu código, editei a resposta para ficar mais claro